# Worker Thread was not updating the visibility status of the button

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I've working with the bulk copy operation with help of BackgroundWorker in wpf application. I call the method DoAction as like below from worker thread

```
private void DoAction()
  {

     .....................
     .....................   // some code goes here and works fine

     //Enable the Explore link to verify the package
     BuildExplorer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // here enable the button to visible and gives error
  }
```

If I visible BuildExplorer button visibility at the end it was saying error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." How can i update the UI Thread staus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only legal to modify the UI from the UI thread in WPF.  Actions like changing visiblity is modifying the UI and can't be done from a background worker.  You need to do this from the UI thread

The most common way to do this in WPF is the following

- Capture `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` in the UI thread
- Call `Invoke` on the captured value from the background thread to do work on the UI thread

For example

```
class TheControl { 
  Dispatcher _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

  private void DoAction() {
    _dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
      //Enable the Explore link to verify the package
      BuildExplorer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's ok. The worker process takes around 5 or 6 mins to complete. Then how can i find out the completion and update the status with help of UI thread ?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah: Use BackgroundWorker buddy or any thread level events

Comment: Thank you. it was helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please marshal the control access if you are accessing from different thread. In Windows and many other OS, A control can be access only by the thread in which it has born. You can not fiddle with it from another thread. in WPF , A dispatcher needs to be associated with a UI thread and you can marshal the call through the dispatcher only.

If long running task than use BackgroundWorker class to get the completion notification

```
var bc = new BackgroundWorker();
    // showing only completed event handling , you need to handle other events also
        bc.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
                                     {
                                        _dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
                                        //Enable the Explore link to verify the package
                                        BuildExplorer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                     };
```